# Show front-end UI from Azure Repos (Github Pages equivalent)

Tags: azure-devops, frontend, static-site, azure-repos

I was recently told by my IT department that I can't use Github as a code repository, so I'm using Azure Repos in Azure Devops.

I am primarily a designer, and my only usage for Github was to render HTML, CSS, and Javascript as a working prototype in Github Pages that can be shared to anyone with an internet connection.

I am *not at all* familiar with Azure DevOps or Azure Repos, is there any way to show my front end code as a generated page using Azure? Would I have to use something like Jekyll or Hugo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to show my front end code as a generated page using
>   Azure? Would I have to use something like Jekyll or Hugo?

Displaying the front-end UI directly in Azure Repos is still a not-supported scenario for now.

[Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/get-started/what-is-repos?view=azure-devops) in `Azure Devops Service` supports `Git` and `TFVC` version control system to manage the code. But it doesn't mean it supports same functions like **Github**, at least Azure Repos itself doesn't have the feature to render `HTML, CSS, and Javascript` and display the front-end UI.

Also, I checked the Azure Devops extensions [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Installs) and didn't find one extension that meet your needs. So I think what you want is now not supported for `Azure Repos`. You may use the `Azure Repos` to host the `HTML, CSS, and Javascript` files like what `Github repos` do, clone it locally and use third-party tool to display the UI when necessary.

Also, you may post a feature request with details about what you want with Azure Devops Repos [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). If it gets enough votes, the team would consider it seriously! Hope all above helps :)